# Different handler within same TR click

Tags: jquery

```
$j('table#thisOne tr:gt(0)').hover(function () {
   if ($j(this).next().length != 0) {
     $j(this).find('td:not(:first-child)').css("background", "#f60").css("cursor", "pointer");
   }
}, function () {
   $j(this).find('td').css("background", "").css("cursor", "auto");
});
```

This code above works fine, i.e. hovering between row 2 to second last row, and second columns.

The following is handling click event for that table:

```
$j('body').delegate("#thisOne tr:gt(0)", 'click', function () { 
    //I want to do something if second column onward clicked, but not first column 
    //which is a checkbox for other handler.
});
```

If column 1 has checkbox, How can I distinguish clicking the checkbox and the entire row. Because I want to have different handler between column1 and the rest of the column.

TIA.

Comment: if you want to different handler in same event you can using if statement.

Comment: Found the solution with 2 click events
`$j('body').delegate("#thisOne tr:gt(0)", 'click', function () {...})`

and 

`$j('body').delegate("#thisOne tr:gt(0) td:first-child", 'click', function (event) {event.stopPropagation();})`

Thank to @Josh-Leitzel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to take advantage of [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). Basically, create your `tr click` handler, and then create a more specific one for your first column. Something like this:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
  // handler1
});

$('tr .col1').click(function(event) {
  // handler2
  event.stopPropagation(); // handler1 will not be called now
});
```

Comment: stop propagation is the key. Thanks Josh.